# How to listen for changes in embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native, changestream

I have a collection  **teams** with sample document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "teamName": "BILALATI6449",
    "tournamentId": "197831"
  },
  "tournamentName": "Amanora Cricket Championship 2021",
  "player1": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player2": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player3": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player4": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player5": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player6": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player7": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player8": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player9": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player10": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "player11": {
    "$oid": "6187d65514f9a67bcf9e8102"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

All the players object have embedded documents from **pointotals**. How can I listen for changes in these documents. I tried this code but id doesn't work.

```
const collection = client.db("mysquad11").collection("pointtotals");

const changeStream = collection.watch();

changeStream.on("change", (next) => {
    if (next.operationType === "update") {
        console.log(next);
    }
});
```

Can somesome help me to tackle the problem. I, only want to listen the changes of embedded documents, not all documents of pointTotals collection.
Sample of document from pointtotals collection is:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6188f5b5a153c12f050fa451"
  },
  "ids": {
    "_id": "113069",
    "tournamentId": "197831"
  },
  "playerName": "Abhijit Tupe",
  "pointsTotal": 426,
  "__v": 0,
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _" I tried this code but id doesn't work."_ ?

Comment: It does not track for changes in embedded document(from pointtotals) in team document. When I make change change in embedded document in pointotal collection, nothing print on console. But, when I make changes in "$oid" of any player, the next object prints on console.

Comment: Are you using the `Mongoose` ODM? Or is it the MongoDB NodeJS Driver? Also, include the collection sample you are trying in your post.

Comment: @prasad_ I am using nodejs driver to implement change stream. But, for all other interaction with database, I am using mongoose

Comment: Maybe try using Mongoose API for the change stream too.

Comment: @prasad_ any reason?

Comment: Just a suggestion to try (I dont have any more suggestions, further).

Comment: Don't know the syntax to implement it in mongoose. If you know any helping material, then share link, it simply helps me to delete one dependency.